# domain doesn't work without [.www]

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web-server, virtualhost, domain

So I set up an Apache Webserver.
Apache is handling the requests and guides them to the web framework flask.
And i bought a domain and configured it with an A Record to my Server Ip.
And now whenever i enter www.mydomain.com it works but entering mydomain.com(wihout www) gets me to my site, but in the top browser window the server IP shows (for ex. 82.213.123.122)

The Apache 000-default.conf file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.de
    ServerAlias mydomain.de
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/flask.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/flask>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead

```
ServerName mydomain.de 
ServerAlias  *.mydomain.de
```